# I have a products database table and each product has an image. Should my table have one column which contains the whole path to the image?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating an API which has a `Products` database table, and each product has an image associated with it. Currently my table looks like this:

```
Table: Products
Columns: id, name, imagePath
```

and one of my records looks like this:

```
1 | product1 | http://localhost:3000/images/products/84b9c559-eac4-45df-89a5-a6b66e830ada.png
```

And when I make a `GET` request for the products from my front-end, I can easily render the image of the product by setting the image tag's src to the `imagePath` field.

Now this is the problem I faced which makes me think this is not the right way to go - I created a POST endpoint that expect an id of a product, and then deletes that product from the database. I'd obviously want to also delete the image that belongs to that product from my file system, however, I am not sure how to build a path to it. To delete it, I need to do this:

```
try {
    await fs.unlink('public/images/products/84b9c559-eac4-45df-89a5-a6b66e830ada.png')
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

So I need to find the name of the product from the `filePath` column in the database - `http://localhost:3000/images/products/84b9c559-eac4-45df-89a5-a6b66e830ada.png`

I can achieve that with some string manipulation and end up with the name of the image - `84b9c559-eac4-45df-89a5-a6b66e830ada.png` and then do something like:

```
try {
    await fs.unlink('public/images/products/' + imageName )
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

I just feel like this way is not the most efficient one. Maybe I need to save the `imageName` along with the `imagePath` inside the products table?

Comment: You could store the image itself in the database. This makes displaying it more complicate as you'd need an extra "page" (but with some image MIME type instead of HTML) that just delivers the image's data. But deleting would be as easy as just deleting the record. Plus the database can now control integrity. There cannot be images in the filesystem that don't belong to a product or products with invalid image paths anymore.

Comment: You might want to allow for the possibility of multiple images per product in the future, in which case, store the image paths in a separate table. My rule-of-thumb is anything larger than 100kB belongs in a file server, and below 100kB can go either in the file server or a database blob